# How to pass value from <asp:textbox> to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a `javascript` function from `<asp:textbox>`. My `javascript` function needs to add value from two `<asp:textbox>`, add them and then pass the value to another `<asp:textbox>`. My `javascript` function is as follows

```
function getAmount() { 
    var total = $('#ItemRate').val() * $('#ItemQty').val();
    $('#ItemAmount').val(total);
}
```

My `<textbox>` is as follows

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="ItemRate" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="ItemQty" onchange="javascript:getAmount()" />  
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="ItemAmount" />
```

Upon running, my console shows the value of total as NaN. How do I solve this one?

Comment: do you use jquery? so why no jquery tag there?

Comment: i added the jquery tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually ASP change the `ID` attribute for each elements which have `runat="server"` attribute.

So you need other attribute for selecting them, eg. `class`.

Try this code:

```
function getAmount() { 
    var total = $('.ItemRate').val() * $('.ItemQty').val();
    $('#ItemAmount').val(total);
}
```

Html:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="ItemRate" id="ItemRate" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="ItemQty" id="ItemQty" onchange="javascript:getAmount()" />  
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="ItemAmount" id="ItemAmount" />
```

Comment: sorry but i changed the `('#ItemRate ')` to `('.ItemRate')` in your answer since we are calling class. Other than that your code worked perfectly

Comment: looks like `('#ItemAmount')` also need to be changed to class selector

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code

```
Value1: <asp:TextBox ID="tbx1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Value2: <asp:TextBox ID="tbx2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<button onclick="Add()">Add</button><br />

Result:<asp:TextBox ID="tbx3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Add()
    {

        var x = document.getElementById('<%= tbx1.ClientID %>').value;
        var y = document.getElementById('<%= tbx2.ClientID %>').value;
     document.getElementById('<%= tbx3.ClientID %>').value=parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

change `value()` to `val()` :

```
function getAmount() { 
    var total = $('#ItemRate').val() * $('#ItemQty').val();
    $('#ItemAmount').val(total);
}
```

Comment: actually that was a typo. the problem lies in `var total` which is being returned as NaN

Answer (score 1):

Try with parsing value in float like below code.

```
  parseFloat("10");
```

Now multiply both value, also check your id get changed or not in browser doing inspect element.